# Does order of the traning data matter when building a CNN model?

Tags: python, keras

I'm reviewing the Keras CNN example located [here](https://keras.io/examples/imdb_cnn/) and i see that the input data has the positive and negative sentiment training samples randomly shuffled. I was wondering if the CNN is sensitive to the ordering of the training data.

For clarity: if my y_train was of shape 100x1, in which 0-50 where all positive sentiments and 50-100 were negative sentiments, would the results be any different compared to when every even index has positive sentiment and odd index has negative?

Answer (score 0):

Shuffling the data when training a neural network in batches might be crucial for the performance of your model. A more detailed discussion on this topic is presented [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24511/why-should-the-data-be-shuffled-for-machine-learning-tasks) on the data science stackexchange.
I just want to add that shuffling is in general beneficial for the evaluation of your model when you do cross validation, for example. In each train-test folds you want to have random samples, so that you can be sure that your model can generalize well.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically for the last epoch, if the last half of the samples were only positive your model might have a slight bias for the positive. However this is why Keras' fit() function has a shuffle feature so it shuffles training samples for every epoch to ensure there is no bias and your model gets to train on different batches get a look at your problem from many different angles. Unless you have a reason to believe you should not be doing this i'd definitely recommend it.